# How to measure the On/Off current ratio in TFETs and MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement

I saw the conventional understandings other questions: [MOSFET ON and OFF current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191396/mosfet-on-and-off-current)

As I know, the off current is not zero, however very small, in the cut-off region. When we discuss TFETs, one of the critical issues is On/Off current ratio. And the characteristics of TFETs are quite different from the MOSFETs'.

Can we measure the On/Off current ratio from transfer and output characteristic curves? If there are many ways to measure, at least I would like to confine it to low power devices. And, I read that somebody talks with the ***figure of merit***. What is it?

Comment: What is a TFET?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Tunneling Field Effect Transistor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How do I measure the On/Off current ratio?

I found the following picture of an output characteristic on Wikipedia (note that the y-axis is log-scale, so the drain-current never reaches zero). I am not familiar with TFET's, but if the principle is similar to that of CMOS we'll be fine.

[image: Transfer curve TFET vs CMOS]

The ON-current would be the current that you achieve at a logical "high" gate-voltage. This high voltage will depend on the process that you're using. Similarly, the OFF-current would be the drain current with a logical "low" gate-voltage. The ratio, I imagine, is then the ratio of these two currents.
Both of these curves were measured at a constant drain-source voltage, and if you wish to measure the worst-case scenario you may want to measure a few curves.

So you simply need to know:

- \$i_{On} = i_{DS}\$ at \$v_{GS}\$ HIGH and \$v_{DS}\$ constant.
- \$i_{Off} = i_{DS}\$ at \$v_{GS}\$ LOW and \$v_{DS}\$ constant.

From which kind of curves you get these numbers don't matter.

### What is a Figure of Merit (FOM)?

A FOM is pretty much an invented quantity that tries to eliminate known intrinsic properties and constraints to compare performance across different technologies, implementations, etc. A FOM is constructed in such a way that a higher FOM is better. The world of FOM's is a pretty vague one, as a FOM can apply to specific target applications, and can change shape depending on how or who you look at it, making it a more subjective part of research. My advise to you is - whenever you're dealing with FOM's - not to get hung-up too much over it.

For example, the OFF-current in a CMOS transistor depends on the width of the transistor (\$i_{Off}\$ ~ \$W\$). So if we say that our CMOS transistor has a lower/better \$i_{Off}\$ than someone else's transistor, then you could just be using a smaller transistor and you might be reaching the wrong conclusion that your technology is better than his.
It makes more sense to calculate \$i_{On}/i_{Off}\$ because this figure is independent of the width, hence the On/Off current ratio can be considered a FOM.

Things can get much more complicated quickly as you find out more and more things. For example, I came across this FOM for CMOS transimpedance amplifiers:

$$FOM = \frac{\sqrt{BW}\cdot R_T\cdot C_T}{Noise\cdot P}$$

(\$BW\$ = bandwidth in GHz, \$R_T\$ is the TIA gain, \$C_T\$ is the input capacitance, \$Noise\$ is the noise in \$pA/\sqrt{Hz}\$ and \$P\$ is the power in mW)
This FOM allows us to compare CMOS TIA's with different BW's, gains, capacitances, noise and power consumption. To the average designer, this *can* be interesting; however, in an application where you're only interested in bandwidth and power consumption is not an issue, this FOM may not be useful to you.

Comment: One question for the Ion in TFETs. Sometimes we encounter a negative resistance region in the output curves. In that case, how can we pick the Vgs or Vds to get the Ion (also Ioff)?

Comment: I doubt that there is a clear-cut answer to that question. The on-off current ratio as a FOM may not even make sense for TFET's if that negative resistance doesn't allow you to justify a comparison with CMOS transistors. Have you checked with the literature on this?

Comment: Not sure what you expected, here two refs. doi.org/10.1007/s11664-016-5120-2 and doi.org/10.1016/j.carbon.2018.04.043 In the first literature, I think they used desired values: I60(instead  Ioff?) ~ 1 μA/μm and Ion ~ 200 μA/μm. And, in the 2nd one, there exists NDR regions on some figures.

Comment: Hi Noki, the first paper explains explicitly how they measure their \$I_{60}\$ and \$I_{ON}\$ currents and which voltages they use for it, and so this allows us to interpret their results. Similarly, DOI 10.1109/JEDS.2014.2326622 also explains how they shift their \$I_D-V_{GS}\$ current to compare everything, and they also state the \$V_{DS}\$ for each of their measurements.
Different \$V_{DS}\$ and \$V_{GS}\$ means different on-off current ratios, but all of them are still valid results. It is up to scientists like you to make sense of in which cases they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The drain current of TFET in the off-state is very low, in the picoamperes or even femtoamperes range. To measure currents that low is a challenge. To tackle this challenge in practical measurements, a parameter "subthreshold swing" is **extracted** from TFET's output characteristics, rather than directly measured.

The drain current in the subthreshold region (a weak inversion in MOSFET) has basically an exponential dependence on overdrive voltage: `~exp(q·(v_GS - V_thresh)/nKT)`, for the source tied to bulk, and `~exp(q·(κ·(V_G - V_thresh) - V_S)/nKT)`, for the source not tied to bulk. In a log-linear plot, the drain current in subthreshold region is linear with a slope that is called the "subthreshold slope (SS)". The MOSFET physics posits and proves that this subthreshold swing (reciprocal SS, [subthreshold swing] = 1/[subthreshold slope]) cannot be less than ca. 60 mV/decade.

For BTBT TFET, a subthreshold region can be coarsely defined as the region where the conduction band of the intrinsic region is still not aligned with the valence band of the P region. Although the TFET physics and device models differ from MOSFET's, there is also an approximately linear region in the drain current-vs-gate voltage log-linear plot for TFET device.

There is a number of methods to extract the threshold voltage (and, with a certain precision, the subthreshold swing) parameters from MOSFET output characteristics. See, for example, https://www-elec.inaoep.mx/seminario2013/ortiz_SNDA13.pdf and http://compass.formfactor.com/2018/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/COMPASS2018-Cheng-Comparative-Vt-Techniques.pdf . Some of these methods (not all, because of an ambiguity in threshold voltage definitions for TFET) can be applied to TFET subthreshold swing parameter extraction, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0038110113003675 and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337610522_Effects_of_Back-Gate_Bias_on_Subthreshold_Swing_of_Tunnel_Field-Effect_Transistor.

I think the answer to your first question ("Can we measure the On/Off current ratio from transfer and output characteristic curves?") is: yes, we can extract the source-drain leakage current component I_off from output characteristics, but only indirectly, with data processing using computations and, to some extent, device model data (there is also the gate-oxide leakage-current component). In the on state (I_on), the drain current is in the microamperes range and can be read directly from output characteristics.

The ratio I_on/I_off improves reliability (noise immunity) of low-power devices and so it is the **figure of merit**. These currents are also autonomous 'figures of merits': a low I_off decreases stand-by power consumption, a high I_on increases fan-out capability of logic gates.

For the importance of the I_on/I_off figure of merit, search *'steep-slope transistors'*, *'steep-slope designs'*. You will find many references, for example, https://rlpvlsi.ece.virginia.edu/sites/rlpvlsi.virginia.edu/files/MWCAS_2017_Final_IEEE_Submitted.pdf and https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/208847741.pdf , each of which discusses advantages of high I_on/I_off ratio in a multifaceted way.

**ADDENDUM**

However exacting the task of their measurement is, subpicoampere currents are routinely measured in research and industry. The SE policy discourages commercial product advertisement and even recommendations on product use, but, having no vested interest in Tektronix, Inc., I venture into mentioning Tektronix's [Low Level Measurements Handbook](https://www.tek.com/document/handbook/low-level-measurements-handbook). Notice FIGURE 4-21: IDS vs. VGS for an Enhancement Mode MOSFET

Also, it is not extraordinary for competent engineers to develop **femtoampere** designs of their own, see https://www.edn.com/design-femtoampere-circuits-with-low-leakage-part-3-low-current-design-techniques/ and https://www.edn.com/achieve-femtoampere-leakage-in-surface-mount-op-amp-layouts/ .

Comment: In your 1st answer, I feel a little ambiguous of the word: **microamperes range**. Does this mean a value satisfying the device to work properly?

Comment: TFETs being experimental devices, I cannot refer you to datasheets. The documents quote the drain current density I_ds/W in A/m or uA/um units. Given the device dimensions, you can calculate the I_on figure for yourself. Typical values are in the uA range. TFET's I_on is intensively discussed. Because of the device's physics, BTBT TFET's I_on is inherently lower compared to MOSFET's. The decreased I_on can limit the fan-out parameter, see the answer's next paragraph.

Comment: In case your question concerns measurement setups, see my edit.